# Validation length component depending on chosen h1/h2

Tags: html, aem, sightly

Where is a correct place in code to write validation(adding maximum lenght on text field) depending on two diference input's. User can chose an textfield size between h1 or h2. When user chose h1 I want to limit text to 10 elements, when chose h2 limit will be 7 elements. I use AEM 6.2.

I try to Validate an htl file, validate an cq_dialog.When I try to validate an htl file I have an problem with implementation ( it doesn't work), but in cq_dialog.xml file I can only validate an text label once, and I can't change a logic that my validation was change depending which size of text user chose.
This is My cq_dialog code and the most comfortable for me will be adding all logic here but I don't know this is posible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
          xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0"
          jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
          jcr:title="Text"
          sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog">
    <content jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
             sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <column jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <title
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            name="./title"
                            fieldLabel="Text"
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                            fieldDescription="Max 10 elements"
                    />
                    <type
                            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/select"
                            fieldLabel="Type"
                            name="./type"
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    >
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <h1 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="H1" value="h1"/>
                            <h2 jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" text="H2" value="h2"/>
                        </items>
                    </type>
                </items>

            </column>
        </items>
    </content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a clientlib and add JS to register a validator for this use case. The clientlib's category must be referenced by the dialog. Using some OOTB category used by the dialog like 'cq.authoring.editor' will make your clientlib work for dialog validation.

Once you have the clientlib set up, register the validator with the granite framework. Refer https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation/js/validation/index.html#validator on how to register the validator.

Here's a sample of how you can do this for your usecase.

```
   var foundationRegistry = $(window).adaptTo("foundation-registry");
   foundationRegistry.register("foundation.validation.validator",{
    selector: "[name='./title']",
    validate: function(el){
        var text = el.value;
        var type = $("[name='./type']").val();
        var limit = type === 'h1' ? 10 : 7;

        var numberOfElements = getNumberOfElements(text); //not sure what number of elements means in your context
        if(numberOfElements > limit){
              return "The input cannot exceed "+limit+ " elements for type "+type;
        }
        //the field is considered invalid if this method returns a string,
       // the string returned is also used as the error message.
    }
  }); 
* the code has not been tested
```

Since the category of the clientlib is generic, this validator will be bound for all dialogs. You can either make the selector of the field more specific or change the clientlib category and explicitly reference it only on this dialog.

Comment: Thanks for help but I have a question. The clientLibs is not a part of AEM which was add on version 6.3? I need to use version 6.2 so I'm not sure this is compatibility in my version.

Comment: This should work on 6.2 as well. There's a depreacted method to add validations, but if my memory serves me right the above answer should work for 6.2 as well. Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll update the answer with the older version

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to use this javaScript code on my aem component(cq_dialog) I'm newbie and this My first component. I add this JS class to my HTL file : <sly data-sly-use.validation="validation.js"/> But this doesn't work.

Comment: Refer this blog http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/clientlibs-explained-example/ . In categories on the clientlib use 'cq.authoring.editor', also you don't have to include the sightly part for your use case as AEM will load 'cq.authoring.editor' within the dialog frame.

Comment: Thank You I will try today this way. Thank You very much and i wrote what is an effect,